# Parsing input from a file using Scanner. JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am brand new to java and I am creating a file directory that stores movies and information about the movies. The movies and info are stored in a file like this:

```
Movie Title 
Rating Year Reviews Month Day Year
```

Title on first line and other info on the second line. So with multiple movies it looks like this:

```
Movie Title
Rating Year Reviews Month Day Year
Movie Title
Rating Year Reviews Month Day Year
Movie Title
Rating Year Reviews Month Day Year
```

...and so on. I have a method that prints the movies to the console but I am running into a problem formatting the movies correctly. The movie info should be formatted like this:

```
   Star Wars     PG    1977   5 stars  1/5/2018
```

Each column should be aligned properly. The title, rating, and year should be left aligned; the number of
stars and date right aligned.

The First time it prints the movie info out exactly how I want, but when I add multiple movies it messes things up. Here is my code, I believe the problem is in the listMovies method where I try to format the output, but I included all my code in case something is messed up somewhere else.

```
public class Directory 
{
   private static final String dir = "data/cs2410-directory.data";
   String mTitle,mRat,mRel,mRev,mM,mD,mY;

public Directory()
{
    mTitle = "Movie Title";
    mRat = "Rating";
    mRel = "Year";
    mRev = "Reviews";
    mM = "Month";
    mD = "Day";
    mY ="Year";
    insertMovie();
    listMovies();
}


private void insertMovie()
{
    PrintWriter dirIn = null;

    try
    {
        dirIn = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir,true));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dirIn.println(mTitle);
    dirIn.println(mRat+" "+mRel+" "+mRev+" "+mM+" "+mD+" "+mY);
    dirIn.close();
    System.out.print("The following movie has been added to the directory:\n");
    System.out.print(mTitle+" ("+mRel+") "+mRat+"\n");
    System.out.print("Stars: "+mRev+"\n");
    System.out.print("Last Watched: "+mM+"/"+mD+"/"+mY+"\n");
}

private void listMovies()
{
    Scanner dirOut = null;

    try
    {
        dirOut = new Scanner(new FileReader(dir));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (dirOut.hasNext()) //PROBLEM
    {
        System.out.printf("%-15s%-10s%-10s%5s%10s/%s/%s\n", dirOut.nextLine(),dirOut.next()
                ,dirOut.next(),dirOut.next(),dirOut.next(),dirOut.next(),dirOut.next());
    }
    dirOut.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Directory();
}
```

This is the output after one movie (running program once) which is how it is supposed to look:

```
The following movie has been added to the directory:
Movie Title (Year) Rating
Stars: Reviews
Last Watched: Month/Day/Year
Movie Title    Rating    Year      Reviews     Month/Day/Year
```

This is after running it twice:

```
The following movie has been added to the directory:
Movie Title (Year) Rating
Stars: Reviews
Last Watched: Month/Day/Year
Movie Title    Rating    Year      Reviews     Month/Day/Year
               Movie     Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
Title     Rating      Year/Reviews/Month
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:858)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1381)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.listMovies(Directory.java:71)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.<init>(Directory.java:32)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.main(Directory.java:79)
```

This is after running it 5 times:

```
The following movie has been added to the directory:
Movie Title (Year) Rating
Stars: Reviews
Last Watched: Month/Day/Year
Movie Title    Rating    Year      Reviews     Month/Day/Year
               Movie     Title     Rating      Year/Reviews/Month
 Day Year      Movie     Title     Rating      Year/Reviews/Month
 Day Year      Movie     Title     Rating      Year/Reviews/Month
 Day Year      Movie     Title     Rating      Year/Reviews/Month
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:858)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1381)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.listMovies(Directory.java:71)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.<init>(Directory.java:32)
    at cs2410.assn3.directory.Directory.main(Directory.java:79)
```

Comment: Does your file end with a newline character?

Comment: @the_storyteller this is the code I use to input a movie into the file: `dirIn.println(mTitle);
    dirIn.println(mRat+" "+mRel+" "+mRev+" "+mM+" "+mD+" "+mY);
    dirIn.close();`

Comment: Scanner doesn't format output, it parses input. Your problem has nothing to do with formattting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, the solution is quite simple:
Add the following line below the System.out.printf() in the dirOut.hasNext() loop.

```
dirOut.nextLine();
```

Your input pattern has two lines; this extra nextLine() advances through the file correctly.

Comment: ...Like I said, brand new to java! LOL! Thank you!